# Loop and Recursion unrolling

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc, template-haskell

```
W_t = M_t[i] if 0 <= t <= 15
W_t = ROTL_1(W_(t-3) XOR W_(t-8) XOR W_(t-14) XOR W_(t-16)) if 16 <= t <= 79
```

This is from the SHA-1 standards. In haskell what you would trivially do is write a recursive function to do this, but to make it more efficient I would like to unroll the whole recursion. Inlining will not work as this might result in exponential blowup of code. What I have in mind is to write TH to generate the constants line `W_0`, `W_1`, `W_2` and so on upto `W_79`.

Another example is for loop unrolling in the case

```
For t=0 to 79:
{
    T = ROTL_5(a) + f_t(b, c, d ) + e + K_t + W_t
    e = d
    d = c
    c = ROTL_30(b)
    b = a
    a = T
}
```

I would like to unroll this loop as well to avoid recursive function calls (and I don't think ghc will be performing this kind of optimizations).

So before I go and write the TH for this I wanted to ask if there is any better way of doing this. Just to say that optimization is very critical here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TH is the "standard" way to do [user-controlled loop unrolling](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-February/056248.html).

Comment: I don't think there is any other way so I will accept this answer.